# Find where the cut wire theorem fails

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

First, to add more context, let me write the theorem in question:

> **Cut wire theorem:**
> If $(X, \tau)$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $A, B \subseteq X$
> are two different closed sets such that every connected component of
> $X$ intersects at most one of them, then there exists $ U, V \in \tau$
> disjoint, such that $A \subseteq U,\,  B \subseteq V,\,\text{ and } U
>  \cup V = X$

I'm trying to find some spaces where this doesn't hold. One of them Hausdorff but not compact and the other one compact but not Hausdorff. I would appreciate any help to find spaces like that. My only idea about this is that such space must be disconnected wich is not quite helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard example for the first case is the subspace of the plane consisting of the lines $[0,1] \times \{ 1/n \}$, $n \in \mathbb N$, and the singletons $\{(0,0)\}$ and $\{(1,0)\}$. The two singletons are connected components but lie in the same quasi-component.

For a non-Hausdorff example, take the quotient of above formed by shrinking each of the lines to a point. (A sequence with two limit points.)